# iOS Shortcuts-app - how do I trim a text field?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

Given the following iOS Shortcuts-app snippet to trim a text string up to the first n (in this case 6) characters, is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
Text "0123456789ABC”
Set Variable String to Text
Replace "^.{0,6}" with "" in Text (regex ON)
Replace Updated Text with "" in String
```

```
Result "012345"
```

Note that text "012" would result in "012"!

In the shortcuts-app, strings are not quoted as in this snippet

[image: Trim text to first 6 characters]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
Text "01234567890ABC”
Match "^.{0,6}" in Text
```

```
Result "012345"
```

[image: Match text shortcut]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Thinkr My original post and the more succinct answer both truncate (I said trim originally) a text string.

Comment: @Allan - I’m unclear as to how I can make it clearer. The original question was “… is there a simpler way of doing this?“. The question code has three steps and the answer code has one step.

Comment: I understand regex, but most of the folks who read this don’t.  You might want to explain what you’re doing here and why.